# How can I make a single datatable operate with "Split Columns" and "Delete Rows" in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The R shiny code below accepts CSV as an input. Because I have "SplitColumn" and "Delete Rows" buttons, the user's use of these two buttons is dependent on how the CSV looks.

It currently works well, but it displays two datatables one by one, which is not a pleasant viewing experience. What should I alter in the code so that only one table is visible and both buttons operate on that datatable?

Since I am new to shiny, could someone help me fix this issue?

**csv data**

```
ID  Type   Range
21  A1 B1   100
22  C1 D1   200
23  E1 F1   300
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
    library(reshape2)
    source('splitColumn_stack.R')
    library(DT)
    

    splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
      newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
      newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
      after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
      after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
      after_merge
    }
    
    ### use a_splitme.csv for testing this program
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
          checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
          actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
          selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', ''),
          actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput("contents"),
          DTOutput("table1")
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(session, input, output) {
      rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
      rv1 <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
    
      observeEvent(input$file1, {
        file <- input$file1
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
        req(file)
    
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
        rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
        updateSelectInput(session, 'selectcolumn', 'select column', names(rv$data))
    
      })
    
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        req(rv$data)
        rv$data
      })
    
      #for removing the selected Rows
      values <- reactiveValues(dfWorking = NULL)
    
      observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
        rv1$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
        values$dfWorking <- rv1$data
      })
    
      observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    
        if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
    
          values$dfWorking <- values$dfWorking[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
        }
      })
    
      output$table1 <- renderDT({
        values$dfWorking
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just use `rv$data`  `reactiveValues` object in all your cases, instead of rv1 or values.

Comment: @YBS, I verified it as per your request and still it displays me both tables, but this time after I pressed the "SplitColumn" option, both tables appeared.  Both the button should be functional on only one data table. How to accomplish this, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one `reactiveValues` object.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
#source('splitColumn_stack.R')
library(DT)

splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}

### use a_splitme.csv for testing this program

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
      selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', ''),
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, 'selectcolumn', 'select column', names(rv$data))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    rv$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]